# Authentication error while updating or deleting record in external list using BCS in SharePointnt hosted app

Tags: wcf, odata, sharepoint-2013, bcs, sharepoint-apps

I have created WCF Data service and put the code like:

```
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<myEdmxEntity>
{
 public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        myEdmxEntity conn = new myEdmxEntity();

        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);

        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;

        config.UseVerboseErrors = true; 
    }
}
```

then service is successfully created and its accessible using "Content type for an external  data source" in SharePoint Provider hosted app.I can browse to the external list and View records and create new records.
However, when i try to update or delete any record, i get the following error:

**LobSystem (External System) returned authentication error.**

In that case i have provided the full permission to farm user in BCS service as well as provide execute permission to that user in application pool too.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved my issue, after surfing lots of blogs and found that just uninstallation of "WebDAVAuthoringRules" from IIS is the cure of your problem.

Thanks,
Rishi